# ASP.NET Code Behind and Page results are mismatched

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, mismatch

Hi
I am developing a website using VS2010. I have started receiving an issue today which is
text boxes on my pages are not populated every time while code behind shows the text is changed.

I have a text box to input an ID and on validation the record is fetched and details are shown in other text boxes. There are certain IDs on which the code behind (while debugging) shows the Text property of all text boxes are changed to reflect the fetched record but after completion of the event, text boxes are shown with previous texts, their texts are not those which were shown in the code behind.

I tried both VS2010 and VS2008. I have dual core machine. "Set Affinity" didn't work.

Please help

Comment: in which event you set the Text? seems something is overwriting the text, it should be in Page_Load as @ajay_whiz suggests

Comment: 100% of the time it is useful to show an example...

Comment: Can anybody tell me the reason when i store a list of objects in ViewState, textboxes are not updated for some of the records (not all) and when i don't store the list in ViewState textboxes are updated for each record i.e. working fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Page_Load event? this event gets called every time there is a postback. Execute your initial code it is advised check for postback.

e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostback)
   {
     //your initial code
   }
}
```

Comment: I am saving a list of objects in ViewState so that i don't need to query the database again and again. This is the issue, once this line is disabled, all fields are populated well and when enabled some of the records are not refreshed. I didn't get WHY?